# How to get Street View panorama image data, android

Tags: android, google-cardboard, google-street-view

How to get Street View panorama image data for android, I want to pass the street view image data to the cardboard view at another java file and then the cardboard will load the image data and display it. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689);

private VrPanoramaView panoWidgetView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment streetViewPanoramaFragment =
            (SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment)
                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.streetviewpanorama);
    streetViewPanoramaFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync( 
            new OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama panorama) {
                    // Only set the panorama to SYDNEY on startup (when no panoramas have been
                    // loaded which is when the savedInstanceState is null).
                    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                        panorama.setPosition(SYDNEY);

                    }
                }
            });
}
```

}